# Why does labels() return what was given to "levels =" and visa-versa?

Tags: r, categories, categorical-data

This is really confusing behavior:

```
x <- factor(1:3, levels = 1:4, labels = letters[1:4])
x
# [1] a b c
# Levels: a b c d

labels(x)
# [1] "1" "2" "3"

levels(x)
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

Why does `labels()` return the values given to `levels =` (though filtered to what was actually used, for some reason), while `levels()` returns what was given to `labels =` (which is also given as `Levels:` when inspecting `x`)?

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior as described in the documentation (see Value section):

> ... For a vector the results is the names or seq_along(x)...

```
> seq_along(x)
[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: @joran that's what implicitly meant but didn't communicate it well. Thanks for clarifying.